# alternative for iterative COPY with LIMIT and OFFSET in POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql

what i am doing right now
i have a database table with 1000 rows
limit, offset and somefile are variables
i iterate and in every iteration i do:

recalculate offset by adding the old value to it
and copy some rows to a csv file

```
COPY (SELECT somevalue1, somevalue2, avg(somevalue3) as avg FROM table
GROUP BY somevalue1 ORDER BY somevalue2 LIMIT Limit OFFSET Offset ) TO \’
SOMEFILE \’ DELIMITER AS \’ \’ CSV HEADER
```

is there a way to copy the rows to different csv files without an iteration within one SQL command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[In 9.3 and above, you can `COPY ... TO PROGRAM ...`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html). The program can be a script that filters the input and changes the output file on the fly. A simple tool like `awk` is suitable for this. It'll only work if the knowledge of the file name can be obtained using only the input data, without access to other parts of the database.

It is unfortunately not possible to COPY from a cursor, as that would be a good solution to your problem, allowing you to run multiple `COPY` commands with different destinations without having to use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`. Unfortunately the `FETCH` command is not legal within a `COPY` query block. You could work around this with a PL/PgSQL function that fetched from the cursor and returned the results, but that's getting cumbersome fast.

Comment: with that script...would i have to realize an iteration ?

Comment: @sakal I have no idea what you are asking. You can use a PL/PgSQL function that does `EXECUTE format(...)` to do `COPY` if you want to iterate. You can also use PL/PgSQL to `FETCH` from a cursor and return the rows.

Comment: well, what i meant was that the COPY TO PROGRAM will do the necessary changes and calculate filenames for certain rows, but i still have to run the COPY several times in order to COPY all rows ....so where do i program the iteration_?

Comment: @sakal Er.... Copy to program can pipe to a program that can switch output files on the fly. Like awk. That was the point.